# Getting a products custom option value (text field)?

Tags: custom-options

How can I get the value of a custom option text field called "My Option"? This is what I have so far:

```
foreach($product->getOptions() as $option) {
    $optionTitle = $option->getTitle();

    if(preg_match('/.*my option.*/i', $optionTitle)) {
        //How can I get the value here? I tried:
        $optionValue = $option->getValue();
        $optionValue = $option['value'];
    }
}
```

The $optionValue var is always empty. Is that the correct way?

Thanks!

Comment: hope this help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9993483/magento-get-custom-option-value-details-from-option-value-id

Best Regards

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that option probably contains several values.

Try this code

```
foreach ($option->getValues() as $oValue) {

}
```

Comment: getValues returns nothing, I already tried.

Comment: than var_dump($option) what does it contain?

Comment: Solved it another way by getting all the items from the cart and iterating those.

Comment: This answer wold return the Values of a Drop Down or similar.  The question is asking to return the value of a text field (assuming the text field has a value).